# "sorry for the inconvenience to you", is that correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I used to use:

> I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Today, I've encountered someone saying:

> I am sorry for the inconvenience to you.

Is that correct? Why or why not?

Answer (score 16):

> I am sorry for the inconvenience **to you**.

This looks grammatical and meaningful to me, but it isn't really natural or idiomatic.  It doesn't break any grammatical rules, but [people don't say it very much.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=39358103)

> I am sorry for **your** inconvenience.

This sounds a little better, but people still don't say it very often.

You don't need to say ***to you*** or ***your***.  It's clear from context who's being inconvenienced: the listener.  Perhaps that's why people don't do so very often.

Or perhaps people just don't use words like these because they don't hear anyone else do it.  After all, we learn language by imitation.  Sometimes there isn't really a logical reason why we say one thing instead of another.

> I am sorry for the inconvenience.
>   I apologize for the inconvenience.
>   I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience.

[These and similar phrases are quite common.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=39358237)

Sometimes people use ***any*** instead of ***the***, particularly if they aren't sure whether or not you've actually been inconvenienced:

> We apologize for any inconvenience.

This is also quite natural.

Answer (score 0):

All expressions are relative and correct. It all depends on expressions and the situation on the ground. e.g.

- I am sorry for the inconvenience.
- I am sorry for any inconvenience.

The word "THE" relates to any type of inconveniences which must have been caused by an action, but the word "ANY" simply says I am not too sure if I have actually inconvenienced you, but all the same I need to apologize in case of any.

So any expression can fly, whether "inconvenience to you or caused you" can fly.